# How does OS X handle IRQs?

Tags: macos, system-information

As a former Windows and Linux user, I've been challenged several times to have hardware devices not share some particular IRQ line.

If I understand correctly, IRQ lines are part of the hardware architecture (x86 for example), and Operating Systems (such as OS X) provide some means to configure peripherals and inspect current usage of interrupt lines.

This can be found at `/proc/interrupts` on Linux systems and on Device Manager on Windows systems.

Where can I see that information on an OS X? Is it never needed?

Comment: I'm going to close this for some rework as it's hard to guess what problem is being solved. If we were to ask a series of questions. "Why are you seeking X, for what will it be used?" this might get refined into something that could be answered and/or get someone to give a long answer instead of "they are handled by the Mach Kernel" or "they are handled in this section of Apple's open source darwin code." (and that level of detail might likely be off-topic, instead of too broad to answer.)

Answer (score 0):

Mac OS X configures the IRQs completely automatically (much like Plug&Play), and does not expose these to the user.

Comment: Is there any way to configure these in the non-GUI UNIX layer of OS X?

Comment: Or at least see what devices have been discovered and assigned some IRQ?

Comment: Apple doesn't make this information available anywhere, because you do not need to see or modify IRQs manually. They are handled in a way that there cannot be conflicts.